# Is there a way to restrict printer access to certain users (Windows/Linux/MacOS), over a local network?

Tags: networking, printing, printer, samba, cups

I have set up a print server, connected to a single printer, using `cups` and `samba` on a Raspberry Pi 4, running Raspbian Buster, on my university’s local network. Currently, anyone on the network can discover the printer and send print jobs. I have to share this printer with a small group of around 10 people and I wish to restrict the ability to send print jobs to those 10 people. Note that, there are Windows and Linux users in this group. I have read the `cups` and `samba` documentation on this, where they ask to “Set allowed users” (`cups`) or set `valid users` (`samba`). This seems confusing to me. By “users”, are they referring to remote user accounts (of those 10 people, who are on different operating systems) or some local user account(s), on the print server itself? In either case, will simply adding the names to `cupsd.conf` (for Linux) and `smb.conf` (for Windows) (in the corresponding directive or field) work? Is there a way to accomplish this by using the IP of those users, instead? How do I go about this? Thanks for your time.

Comment: what model printer?

Comment: @SQLTemp Epson L130. It’s a single function printer and not a network printer.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas Well, you're not wrong. I just meant, it's not a network printer, out of the box, and I set it up as one.